# How to hide comment during first run with Crosswalk Lite?

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I want to use Crosswalk Lite plugin in my hybrid app. I did it and works fine but during first run appears this comment that the APK must be decompressed. Ok, I know that it has to stay but I want it to don't pop up. How can I do it? And one more question. Is this possible that Crosswalk Lite deleted (doesn't support) audio (mp3) files from my zip file?

Comment: “Is this possible that Crosswalk Lite doesn't support mp3 files” Of course. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43033247/1101509

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer.