# How do I add media codecs support to Crosswalk while using the Cordova plug-in?

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I'm building a PhoneGap app which needs to play AAC audio. It works well using the native `WebView`, but I would like to use Crosswalk on a build targeting APIs 16-20 because some CSS features in my app do not work at all on Android 4.x.

When I make a copy of the project to add Crosswalk Lite, I can see that the app works except for the `<audio>` element pointing to a AAC file. This is because [Crosswalk does not ship with proprietary codecs by default](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Enable-MultiMedia-in-Crosswalk).

The linked page says:

> To build Crosswalk with these codecs, a developer must run the build
>   with the “must accept a EULA” switch turned on:
>
> ```
> $ xwalk/gyp_xwalk -Dmediacodecs_EULA=1
> ```
>
> Then build Crosswalk. The *ffmpegsumo.dll* or *libffmpegsumo.so* in
>   the build output directory will contain the proprietary codecs.
>
> Refer to [Crosswalk Build Instruction](http://crosswalk-project.org/#contribute/building_crosswalk) for more details.

However, I am adding Crosswalk using the suggested plug-in, thus I get pre-built libraries without proprietary codecs:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview  --variable XWALK_MODE="lite" --save
```

How can I integrate proprietary codecs in the Cordova Crosswalk plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to understand the (convoluted) process of building everything. This answer deals with the process of compiling a custom build of the full Crosswalk (not the lite version).

Actually, **I decided to finally use the standard build** and replace AAC audio with MP3s, but I thought this answer could be useful for future reference.

## Environment

I compiled Crosswalk in a Ubuntu 16.04 Docker container to avoid "polluting" my system and to ensure I had the right Linux version. The standard image is pretty barebones so I installed some dependencies. I also set up a shared folder to access the compiled files:

```
docker run -it -v /home/andrea/shared:/shared ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash
apt update
apt install -y python git nano lsb-release sudo wget curl software-properties-common
export EDITOR=nano # life it too short to learn vi
```

Finally, it is necessary to [add the multiverse repositories](https://askubuntu.com/q/89096/271):

```
apt-add-repository multiverse
```

> **Note:** this procedure needs a lot of space. Make sure to have at least 25GB of free space before continuing.

## Requirements

Install the `depot_tools` as outlined [in the documentation](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra-docs/flat/depot_tools/docs/html/depot_tools_tutorial.html#_setting_up):

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/depot_tools
```

Initialize a working directory with:

```
mkdir crosswalk-checkout
cd crosswalk-checkout
export XWALK_OS_ANDROID=1
gclient config --name src/xwalk https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk.git
```

Then edit the config file with `nano .gclient` and add the following line:

```
target_os = ['android']
```

Save the file.

## Fetching the source

Attempt a first sync with:

```
gclient sync
```

This command **will fail** but it's OK. The instructions say:

> Do not worry if `gyp_xwalk` fails due to missing dependencies; installing them is covered in a later section, after which you can run `gyp_xwalk` manually again.

Adjust the `install-build-deps.sh` file and then run it:

```
sed -si "s/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/g" src/build/install-build-deps.sh
sudo ./src/build/install-build-deps-android.sh
```

Run `gclient sync` again and wait until it finishes correctly.

## Building

By inspecting the files `src/xwalk/build/common.gypi` and `src/tools/mb/mb_config.pyl`, we can see that we need to add `ffmpeg_branding="Chrome"` in the build arguments.

To prevent an error later on, install the development package related to libnotify:

```
sudo apt install libnotify-dev
```

Move to the `src` directory and open the configuration:

```
cd src/
gn args out/Default
```

Ensure the content is as follows:

```
import("//xwalk/build/android.gni")
target_os = "android"
is_debug = false
ffmpeg_branding = "Chrome"
use_sysroot = false
```

The parameters `use_sysroot = false` prevents yet another error. When saving the file, you should see something like this:

```
Waiting for editor on "/home/utente/crosswalk-checkout/src/out/Default/args.gn"...
Generating files...
Done. Wrote 6060 targets from 1003 files in 2416ms
```

Issue `cd ..` and run `gclient sync` again.

Finally, to build the core library do:

```
cd src/
ninja -C out/Default xwalk_core_library
```

This will build the library for ARM, producing an AAR file located at:

```
src/out/Default/xwalk_core_library.aar
```

Copy this file **in a safe place.**

## Building for x86

Get back to the args with:

```
gn args out/Default
```

Add the following line:

```
target_cpu = "x86"
```

Save the file, run `gclient sync` again and then repeat the `ninja` command. Make a copy of the new AAR file which now contains the x86 libraries.

## Using the AAR files

The standard Cordova Crosswalk plug-in uses a single AAR file with libraries for both platforms. [This message](http://narkive.com/x87IGj9G:2.608.332) by Raphael Kubo da Costa suggests how to produce this single archive:

> AAR files are just zip files; **given the only difference between the ARM
>   and x86 AAR files are the different shared libraries, you can use
>   something like `zipmerge` or anything that merges zip files** (or even
>   extract everything into some directory and then create one new zip file)
>   to build one final, multi-architecture AAR archive.

Finally, to *use* the custom built AAR file in the Cordova plug-in, see [How to change the Crosswalk version used by the Cordova Crosswalk Webview plugin](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/using-custom-crosswalk-in-cordova-plugin.html).